# Google Oauth in webview deprecated

Tags: ionic-framework, android-webview, google-oauth, hybrid-mobile-app

I am currently developing a mobile application using the ionic framework.  We recently decided to begin integrating social logins into the application.  Soon after adding google oauth, a notification indicating a deprecation of oauth requested through webviews in 2016/17 began appearing.  After researching the error I found the following [article](https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html).  From my understanding cordova is run entirely using web views.

Does this mean authentication via oauth in an Ionic / Cordova app will now be impossible for both Android and iOS?  I have been researching for an entire day trying to find a work around ( Getting a call back from the system browser to my ionic application ) to no avail.

Does anyone have any experience or similar concerns who could share their experience with this news?

Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the ionic team has pulled down this article: http://blog.ionic.io/google-oauth-changes/
Hopefully it will be back up soon.

For now, refer to this plugin, which I am almost positive was the recommendation:
https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus

Answer (score 2):

Some explanations from the Ionic team :

http://blog.ionic.io/google-oauth-changes/

Comment: Hey, appreciate the heads up on that.  Was wondering what I was going to do once April came around.